# c# Show Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, I'm struggling a little bit here. I am writing a windows console application in C# and have just made a login form for the application called frmLogin.
I tried using the MS documented method of;

```
Form f = new Form();
f.ShowDialog();
```

but this obviously loads/displays a blank form and not the form I defined in the form designer.

In my main application, I want to be able to show the login form programmatically, but when I try to use;

```
frmLogin.ShowDialog();
```

it tells me that "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()'

In the old days, I could show a form by simply using the above snippet of code. So, obviously something has changed since the last time I wrote a windows console app.

Can someone show me the error of my ways?

Comment: You need to post more of your code.  Are you even instantiating your frmLogin?

Comment: What is the class name of your frmLogin. Use that instead of the generic form class in your new statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This creates a new instance of type `Form`:

```
Form f = new Form();
```

Which, of course, is a blank form.  It would appear that your type is called `frmLogin`.  Normally this sounds like a variable name and not a class name, but the error you're getting here tells me that it's a class:

```
frmLogin.ShowDialog();
```

Given that, then the quickest way to solve your problem would be to create an instance of your form and show it:

```
frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
login.ShowDialog();
```

**However**, in keeping with naming standards and conventions (to help prevent future confusion and problems), I *highly* recommend renaming the form itself to something like:

```
LoginForm
```

Then you can use something like `frmLogin` as the variable name, which is a much more common approach:

```
LoginForm frmLogin = new LoginForm();
frmLogin.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: This is precisely what I needed! Thank you! I have been out of the .NET programming world for nearly 10 years. So, got a bit rusty in the interim.

Comment: If you want to save space, try `new LogingForm().ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that with the code snippet you took from Microsoft, you were just building the base Type. You need to build your form. So instead of `new Form`, you build a `new frmLogin`:

```
var f = new frmLogin();
f.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

If this doesn't solve your problem, I will delete my answer but, I am assuming that you aren't instantiating your form:

```
Form2 frmLogin = new Form2();
frmLogin.ShowDialog();
```

This works just fine for me.  Although personally, I would simply use the `.Show()` method:

```
Form2 frmLogin = new Form2();
frmLogin.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the object of the FORM you are trying to open 
for instance "frmStudent"

**Method 1:**

```
frmStudent obj = new frmStudent();
obj.Show();
```

**Method 2:**

It will open the form , but you can't move to another form until you close it.

```
frmStudent obj = new frmStudent();
obj.ShowDialog();
```