# C# form application(how to show(); a second form first using a button

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I created 2 forms.1st form was created with a home menu and the second form is my login page.But the login form should come first.when running the code the 1st form appears first.But I need to get the second form first.what should I do?

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 ss = new Form1();
            ss.Show();
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but can you be more clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Show Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939256/c-sharp-show-windows-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to Program.cs and do this

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: No problem Thumsi :)